# Problemas com tabela no IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

No IE, as células do `tbody` não aceitam os valores do CSS.

```css
td:first-child{
  width: 52%;
}
```

Criei um *jsFiddle* com o html/css da tabela:

http://jsfiddle.net/rqj6r/1/

Comment: Qual versão do IE?

Comment: Estou testando no IE 9

Comment: Nunca me deparei com uma dessa, bom saber!

Comment: Marcelo, encontrou a solução da pergunta ou colocou aqui um remendo e procura a solução correcta/defenitiva? No caso da primeira então é melhor remover a resposta da pergunta e colocar uma nova resposta e aceitá-la.

Answer (score 3):

Tente adicionar essa meta:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```

Tentou usar os hacks?

Tem alguns aqui:

```
#element {
    color:orange;
}
#element {
    *color: white;    /* IE6+7, doesn't work in IE8/9 as IE7 */
}
#element {
    _color: red;     /* IE6 */
}
#element {
    color: green\0/IE8+9; /* IE8+9  */
}
:root #element { color:pink \0/IE9; }  /* IE9 */
```

Fonte: http://jsfiddle.net/ENp5A/

Comment: Tentei usar width: 52%\0/IE8+9; mas nada aconteceu.

Comment: Já estou usando <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

Answer (score 3):

O seu documento está com a tag `<doctype>` bem definida?

Tente usar o doctype esoecífico, que dispare o "modo padrão" no IE, como por exemplo `<!doctype html>`, que deverá ser inserido no começo do documento HTML.

A pseudo classe `:first-child` é um das muitas features de CSS que não são suportadas pelo IE no "Quirks Mode". Veja mais sobre Quirks Mode em http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode.

Veja também a documentação da Microsoft sobre esse tema:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc848865%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12383068/tdfirst-child-does-not-seem-to-work-in-ie

Answer (score 1):

**RESOLVIDO**

O problema estava no :before

```
tbody:before {
  line-height:10px;
  content:"-";
  color: transparent;
  display:block;
}
```

Alterei para:

```
tbody:before {
  height:10px;
  content:"";
  display:block;
}
```

Isso eliminou o espaço entre o thead e o tbody no IE, mas pelo menos corrigiu a tabela.